# What kind of people are inside this building?

Tags: word, visual, lateral-thinking

I've "drawn" here a building with a backdrop of a night sky:

```
┛━━┗╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋
┃┛━┏╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋
┛┏┓━┻━━━┻┗┛┗┛┻━━┗
┃┛━┗┫━━┃┃┓┏┃┃┫━┗┃
┃┃╋┃┃┃━━┣┓┏┫┏┫━┏┃
┓┏╋┓┳━━━┳━━┳━┳━━┏
```

However, can you tell me what the people inside are like?

Comment: https://i2.wp.com/gifrific.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/What-is-this-A-Center-For-Ants-Zoolander.gif

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If we modify the drawing by

> turning each character upside down, we get this:
>  `┌──┐╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋`
>  `│┌─┘╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋`
>  `┌┘└─┬───┬┐┌┐┌┬──┐`
>  `│┌─┐├──││└┘││├─┐│`
>  `││╋│││──┤└┘├┘├─┘│`
>  `└┘╋└┴───┴──┴─┴──┘`

And we can see clearly that

> the people there are ʎzɐɹɔ -- er, I mean **crazy**!

Comment: Equivalently by doing the same thing to rows and columns instead of characters, we get a clearer picture.

Comment: [um, sure...](https://fsymbols.com/generators/carty/)